# Why am I unable to set innerHTML on the document?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a button that you click on and it will do the calculations for the user's age and my JavaScript code will write the user's age on the document itself using innerHTML. I don't understand why it's not working. I'm getting no response not even an error.

Here's my JavaScript:

```
let btn = document.getElementById("btn");

  btn.addEventListener('click',howOldAreYou)

  function howOldAreYou(){

  let age= document.getElementById("year").value
  let currentYear = 2021
  
  let howOld= currentYear - age;

  document.innerHTML= howOld;

}
```

Comment: [Documents](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) don’t have an `innerHTML` property. Creating one is meaningless.

Comment: [Duplicate](//google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+%22document.innerHTML%22+not+working) of [javascript document.innerHTML set content of whole document](/q/6758081/4642212).

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `document.body.innerHTML` or `document.documentElement.innerHTML`.

`document` is not an element, and thus does not have the `innerHTML` property.

Comment: @carringtonCodes If it helped, please consider accepting! :) [How do I accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are not using the innerHTML element property correctly, it should be `yourElementId.innerHTML` instead of `document.innerHTML`

Try this:

```js
btn.addEventListener('click',function(){
  let age = document.getElementById("year").value;
  let currentYear = 2021;
  let howOld = currentYear - age;
  result.innerHTML = howOld;
});
```

```html
<button id="btn">Calculate</button>
<input id="year"/>
<div id="result"></div>
```